# "Importing test library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SSHLibrary'

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

```
"message": "Importing test library 'SSHLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SSHLibrary'\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  None\nPYTHONPATH:\
```

python version: 3.12
robot framwork : 6.0
sshlibrarry :3.8.0
visual studio 2019

still I see the import error .

please help in resolve.

what exact version i need to have here ?
i switched to python 2.7. still it does not help
anyone facing similar issues?

Comment: quick google brings up: https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-robotframework-sshlibrary/
Might be of help?